# Solving a system of equations problem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm ytrying to solve the following for $x$ as an expression of the other variable (as few as possible)

$$a+bx+(n-1)de=0$$
$$f+gx+(n-1)he=0$$

I'm not sure how to solve this.

---

I tried equating both, but I cant get rid of $(n-1)$ or $e$.
$$
a+bx+(n-1)de=f+gx+(n-1)he
$$

I think the answer is $$x=\frac{fh-ad}{bd-gh}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the other variable? Is it $e$? It's not clear from your post

Comment: $x$ in term o the other variable?  I count $7$ other variables?  I imagine $a,b,f,g, d,h$ are supposed to be constants but is $n$ variable?  Or $e$?

Comment: "I cant get rid of (n−1) or e"  Why do you need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other variable is $$y=(n-1)e$$ as it seems to be from your own attempts and the following quote:

> I tried equating both, but I cant get rid of $(n−1)$ or $e$.

then the solution for $x$ is: $$x=\frac{d f-a h}{b h-d g}$$

And the other variable is:

$$y=(n-1)e=\frac{a g-b f}{b h-d g}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: eliminate $\,n\,$ between the equations, then solve $(1)$ for $\,x\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
{a+bx+(n-1)de = 0 \quad \mid \cdot\,h \\
f+gx+(n-1)he = 0 \quad \mid \cdot\,d}
\end{align}
\quad\Bigg| \,-\, \Bigg| \\[5px]
$$
$$\require{cancel}
ah+bhx+\cancel{(n-1)deh}  - \big(\,fd + gdx + \cancel{(n-1)hed}\,\big) = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

a+bx= (1-n)(de)

f+gx= (1-n)(he)

so

(a+bx)/(f+gx)= (1-n)(de)/(1-n)(he)

for n not equal to 1 and e not equal to 0, we can simplify further

(a+bx)/(f+gx)= d/h

ah+bhx= df+dgx

(bh-dg)x= df-ah

x= (df-ah)/(bh-dg)